# Chrome HTML5 form validation issue

Tags: forms, html, google-chrome, validation

When you type `3.14` for example, and press enter - validation popup appear. As should be fixed number (by default step=1). But when you type some string, e.g. `"hello"` and press enter - form submit. Why?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/keeD2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `required` to the field:

```
<form action="#">
<input type="number" required/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/keeD2/2/

Comment: Yes, it's quick hack. I also tried that. But field should not be required. I'm wondering is it Chrome bug?

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv I don't know if it is a bug perse just that i have a solution for you or others

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools, it's not a bug. Look at the input type for number. I'm also curious as to why it's not working as it should. Have you tried running it on your browser ?

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp